# How to show list of user using reflection

Tags: c#, reflection

I have library and console program. This program load dynamically library. The program create instance of class user and modified some values. After that the program show result. I try write some code, but it's not compile. Can you help me fix this code?
Code of library:

```
public class Class1
{
    List<User> user;
    public Class1()
    {
        user = new List<User>() { new User() { name = "Smith", age = 19 }, new User() { name = "Mitchell", age = 41 } };
    }
}
public class User
{
    public String name;
    public int age;
}
```

Code of program:

```
            Assembly asm = Assembly.LoadFile(@"C:\TestLibrary.dll");
            Type Class1 = asm.GetType("TestLibrary.Class1") as Type;
            Type User = asm.GetType("TestLibrary.User") as Type;
            var testClass = Activator.CreateInstance(Class1);
            MemberInfo[] List = Class1.GetMember("user");
            FieldInfo field = (FieldInfo)List[0];
            List<User> users = (List<User>)field.GetValue(testClass);
            users[0].name = "Scott";
            users[1].age = 21;
            foreach (User us in users)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("User: {0}, Age: {1}",us.name,us.age);
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify the correct [BindingFlags](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.reflection.bindingflags), otherwise only public members will be returned (in your case `user` is private):

```
MemberInfo[] List = Class1.GetMember("user", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
```